# ffprobe 4.4 doesn't show Frame Side Data

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I created a library to integrate with ffmpeg via CLI. In tests I verify that ffprobe output can be parsed. One of the tests checks that with `-show_frames` option frame data and side data are parsed correctly.

Recently tests started to fail because of absent frame side data in output. After an investigation I found that it happened because of ffmpeg & ffprobe update.

With ffprobe 4.3.1 side data is present:

```bash
docker run --entrypoint="ffprobe" collelog/ffmpeg:4.3.1-alpine-amd64 -show_frames -of flat https://samples.ffmpeg.org/3D/car.avi
...
frames.frame.2929.color_primaries="unknown"
frames.frame.2929.color_transfer="unknown"
frames.frame.2929.chroma_location="unspecified"
frames.frame.2929.side_data_list.side_data.0.side_data_type="QP table data"
frames.frame.2929.side_data_list.side_data.1.side_data_type="QP table properties"
```

With ffprobe 4.4 side data is absent:

```bash
docker run --entrypoint="ffprobe" collelog/ffmpeg:4.4-alpine-amd64 -show_frames -of flat https://samples.ffmpeg.org/3D/car.avi
...
frames.frame.2929.color_range="unknown"
frames.frame.2929.color_space="unknown"
frames.frame.2929.color_primaries="unknown"
frames.frame.2929.color_transfer="unknown"
frames.frame.2929.chroma_location="unspecified"
```

Is it a bug?

Comment: Are these all the sidedata dumped?

Comment: yes, from https://samples.ffmpeg.org/3D/car.avi it's all side data shown